# Cross platform ESLint command to run on current directory recursively?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm looking to create a **cross-platform**  `package.json` command to lint all .js, .ts, .tsx files in the current directory, recursively.

Here's what I've tried.

1. This is directly from the [ESLint CLI docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface).

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts,.tsx",
}
```

*nix - ✅ Windows -

On Windows...

> No files matching the pattern "." were found.
>   Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

2. GLOB matching pattern.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint **/*.js **/*.ts **/*.tsx",
}
```

*nix -  Windows - ✅

3. GLOB matching pattern with quotes.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint '**/*.js' '**/*.ts' '**/*.tsx'",
}
```

*nix - ✅ Windows -

This is a cross-platform project with developers using Mac, Linux, and Windows.

How do I get this single command to work on all three?

Comment: Just curious if using removing the single quotes fixes the issue? `eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx`

Comment: @DanielBank, no it doesn't. The `.` is the issue. I accidentally left it off the example code.

Comment: Why not just run both? using &&

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im working on similar problems right now.
I had success with something like.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\" \"**/*.ts\" \"**/*.tsx\"",
}
```

or shorter

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\"",
}
```

Replacing single quotes with escaped double quotes is actually a pattern not eslint specific.

Maybe it helps.

Comment: I was finally able test this and it worked perfectly. Thanks! 